Collisions with BSP geometry
I'm making an engine with BSP based levels. I have a solid leaf BSP tree, I already can test if point lies in the solid or empty leaf, however I can't understand how to do the same with a bounding box.
I tried to add bounding box min and max sizes to velocity:
public bool CanMove(Vector3 _velocity) {
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(_velocity.X > 0 ? _velocity.X + max.X : _velocity.X + min.X, _velocity.Y > 0 ? _velocity.Y + max.Y : _velocity.Y + min.Y, _velocity.Z > 0 ? _velocity.Z + max.Z : _velocity.Z + min.Z);
    return IsPointInNode(center + velocity, map.coreNode);
}

bool IsPointInNode(Vector3 position, MapNode node) {
    if (node.isLeaf) {
        return node.isSolid;
    }
    return Vector3.Dot(node.plane.normal, position) + node.plane.distance < 0 ? IsPointInNode(position, node.frontChild) : IsPointInNode(position, node.backChild);
    }
}

it worked, however only min or max bounding box size can be applied at once so clipping occurred.
I'm aware of quake's collision hull BSPs, however it doesn't seem good for me as I expect there to be a lot of different collider sizes and storing separate trees for each of them doesn't seem appealing.
Are there any better methods to check bounding box collisions using BSP or should I just store raw brushes inside of a map and use them for collision detection?

In your question, you ask how to check if a bounding box lies in a solid or empty leaf, but in your code, you are trying to write CanMove, which presumably is checking whether a bounding box, defined by Vector3 min and max, can move along a velocity vector without colliding with the bsp.  These are two different but related problems with fairly straightforward solutions, but you should first clarify your question for a proper response.

I've figured this out. Instead of having a separate tree with expanded walls (planes) you can add hitbox size to plane distance when traversing BSP tree itself:
return Vector3.Dot(node.plane.normal, position) + (node.plane.distance + hullSize) < 0 ? IsPointInNode(position, node.frontChild) : IsPointInNode(position, node.backChild);

And if your hitbox has different sizes on different dimensions you can just multiply plane normal by hitbox size:
float hullSize = Math.Abs(node.plane.normal.X * size.X) +
                   Math.Abs(node.plane.normal.Y * size.Y) +
                   Math.Abs(node.plane.normal.Z * size.Z);

